# How do I create multiple dataframes that are named based on the value of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with about 2.5M rows and would like to split this up into about 10000 rows (one for each unique value of **TICKER**), and to have the name be df(i) for each value of i.

For example, for the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ticker": ["A", "A", "BB", "BB", "CCC", "CCC", "A"],
  "date": ["04-30-2020", "07-30-2020", "05-31-2020", "08-31-2020", "06-30-2020", "09-30-2020", "10-31-2020"],
"assets": ["40","50","60","70","80","90","100"]})
```

I would want a loop that does the following:
for every i (i=unique value of ticker)
dfi=df(df.ticker==i)

so for example
if the ith value was CCC:

```
dfCCC=df(df.ticker='CCC')
print(dfCCC)
```

```
      ticker       date        assets 
0      CCC       06-30-2020      80 
1      CCC       09-30-2020      90
```

Is this possible and if so how would this be done?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Avoid flooding many data frames in global environment. Instead, consider a *single* dictionary of data frames using `groupby`: `ticker_dfs = {k:v for k,v in df.groupby()}`. Then access each by key: `ticker_dfs['CCC']`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do with `groupby`:

```
for k,d in df.groupby('ticker'):
    print(d)
    print('-'*30)
```

Output:

```
  ticker        date assets
0      A  04-30-2020     40
1      A  07-30-2020     50
6      A  10-31-2020    100
------------------------------
  ticker        date assets
2     BB  05-31-2020     60
3     BB  08-31-2020     70
------------------------------
  ticker        date assets
4    CCC  06-30-2020     80
5    CCC  09-30-2020     90
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this,

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"ticker": ["A", "A", "BB", "BB", "CCC", "CCC", "A"],
"date": ["04-30-2020", "07-30-2020", "05-31-2020", "08-31-2020", "06-30-2020", "09-30-2020", "10-31-2020"],
"assets": ["40","50","60","70","80","90","100"]})

import sys

thismodule = sys.modules[**name**]

ls = df.ticker.unique().tolist()

for i in ls:
setattr(thismodule, "df"+i, df[df.ticker==i])

display(dfA,dfBB,dfCCC)

Output

[image: multiple_dfs_with_random_names]

Note:

- If you need to refer to those df names in a loop, please use the following:

for i in ls:
print(eval("df"+i))

- **name** is enclosed within double underscores on both sides(underscore underscore name underscore underscore)