# Pandas Creating multiple data frames using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am looking for efficient Python codes to:

**1. Create multiple data frames
2. Loop over the multiple data frames**

For instance, in my code:

```
os.chdir(EU_path)
csv_files = glob.glob(EU_path + '\*.csv')
list_EU_data = []
for filename in csv_files:
    data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    list_EU_data.append(data)
```

`list_EU_data` is a list of 10 csv files of product sales from 10 European countries. For instance, `list_EU_data[0]` returns a data frame with columns related to sales information.

Here, I want to create multiple data frames while pre-processing data frames, for instance,

First select columns

```
EU[0] = list_EU_data[0].iloc[:, [0, 1]]
EU[1] = list_EU_data[1].iloc[:, [0, 1]]
...continues...
EU[9] = list_EU_data[9].iloc[:, [0, 1]]
```

Next, from each of the data frames, I want to replace 0 values by 1 and iterate all the data frames:

```
EU[0].iloc[:, 1] = EU[0].iloc[:, 1].replace(0, 1)
EU[1].iloc[:, 1] = EU[1].iloc[:, 1].replace(0, 1)
...continues...
EU[9].iloc[:, 1] = EU[9].iloc[:, 1].replace(0, 1)
```

Using for loop, what's the most efficient ways to write the above code?

Comment: what is code for `1. Create multiple data frames` ?

Comment: I've updated code in my post to show data files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need loop solution working with list of `DataFrame`s:

```
for i, df1 in enumerate(EU):
    df1 = df1.iloc[:, [0, 1]]
    df1.iloc[:, 1] = df1.iloc[:, 1].replace(0, 1)
    EU[i] = df1
```

Also is possible change your code:

```
os.chdir(EU_path)
csv_files = glob.glob(EU_path + '\*.csv')
list_EU_data = []
for filename in csv_files:
    data = pd.read_csv(filename)
    data = data.iloc[:, [0, 1]]
    data.iloc[:, 1] = data.iloc[:, 1].replace(0, 1)
    list_EU_data.append(data)
```

Comment: In your first chunk of code, 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'iloc'

Comment: @SuhwanChung - Here `df` is not list, but DataFrame before split.

Comment: @SuhwanChung - now understand better, what need, so answer was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my comment on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64798278/9967586
for creating multiple data frames and looping over those dfs